# Why is Office 2010 asking me to choose one of only one potential account to open a restricted document

Tags: active-directory

We have implemented an AD Rights Management System in our domain. Occassionally, when I send a protected email to someone in my domain or someone sends one to me, I will be prompted with a dialog box that sys

> "Select one of the following user accounts to create or open content
>   with restricticted permission. To use an account not listed below,
>   click Add"

The issue is that there is only one account to choose from and when I select it, I am able to open the document.

We have just recently enabled a rights management "Trusted User Domain" with a partner company. I cannot verify whether or not this problem began after that change, but there it is definitely a strong possibility. I think this might be a bug in office 2010, but cannot find any documenation stating this. Can anyone confirm that this is a known issue?